Using {!GETRECORDID} for a ListView custom Button to perform Mass Action using a flow (non-JavaScript)
I have created a custom button  for the Order List View layout that looks like this:
/flow/cbn_Create_new_Contacts_from_a_List_of_Orders?orderids={!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Order)}

Parameter orderids is a collection text variable in the flow: cbn_Create_new_Contacts_from_a_List_of_Orders


When I select several order records from the list view and click the custom button, I get an error. What could be the issue and can we use what I already hve without setting up REQUIRESCRIPT javascript content?  See the error below :



Is this in Lightning or Classic? This answer will likely be helpful as well

@KrisGoncalves it is in lightning but I forgot to do one thing in Program Automation Settings and that was to add the "Enable  Lightning Runtime for Flows" setting. That seemed to fix everything. Also when creating the ids variable you have to check "Input" since a List View Button is loading these IDs into the flow for processing.

Thanks to @KrisGoncalves who gave me a hint.
However, I discovered that there were two issues

I forgot to do one thing in Program Automation Settings and that was to add the "Enable  Lightning Runtime for Flows" setting.
Also when creating the ids collection variable you have to check "Input" direction since a List View Button is loading these IDs into the flow for processing.
Once I did this , I hae no more issues.

